# How do I display a key with values in two different dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, display

I have two dictionaries with the same keys but different values and need to display them in column form.

I have tried using:

```
print(price.keys())
print(price.values())
print(stock.values())
```

They need to be displayed as such:

apple
price:2
stock:0

Comment: There's no guarantee the two dictionaries will have the same order; iterate over one set of keys and pull out the values for both.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
for k, v in price.items():
    print("%s price: %s stock: %s" % (k, v, stock[k]))
```

should work. `.items()` will give you key and valu for the current dict. Now you also know the key is present in the other dict, so directly reference it with the key.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a loop:

```
for key in price:
    print("{}:{}\t{}\t".format(key, price[key], stock[key])
```

[Check this out](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3) for more info on .format() (super useful for formatting your output). I'd check out the padding section if you want to format into columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you have same keys in both the dictionaries, you can write:

```
price = {'apple': 20, 'orange': 30, 'banana': 40}
stock = {'apple': 2, 'orange': 3, 'banana': 4}
for i in stock.keys():
    print("%s price: %s stock: %s" %(i, price[i], stock[i]))
```

Output:

```
apple price: 20 stock: 2
orange price: 30 stock: 3
banana price: 40 stock: 4
```